# Plot date and time (x axis) versus a value (y axis) using data from txt file (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, graph

### hi guys below is my attempted code, how can i plot date and time(x-axis) versus a value (y-axis)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
t = []

fig = plt.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')

readFile = open('data.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if plotPair in '. ':
       # skip. or space
       continue
    if idx > 1:  # to skip the first line
        xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        t.append(time_string)
        y.append(float(xAndY[1]))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='blue')
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)

plt.title('IRRADIANCE')
plt.xlabel('TIME')

plt.show()
```

this is my txt file:

```
TimeStamp,Irradiance
21/7/2014 0:00,0.66
21/7/2014 0:00,0.71
21/7/2014 0:00,0.65
21/7/2014 0:00,0.67
21/7/2014 0:01,0.58
21/7/2014 0:01,0.54
21/7/2014 0:01,0.63
21/7/2014 0:01,0.65
21/7/2014 0:02,0.64
21/7/2014 0:02,0.63
21/7/2014 0:02,0.63
21/7/2014 0:02,0.64
.
.
. 
.
22/7/2014 23:57,0.53
22/7/2014 23:58,0.69
22/7/2014 23:58,0.61
22/7/2014 23:58,0.65
22/7/2014 23:58,0.59
22/7/2014 23:59,0.63
22/7/2014 23:59,0.67
22/7/2014 23:59,0.68
22/7/2014 23:59,0.58
```

but it doesn't seem to work (my code):
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'

Comment: What does `time_string` look like?  And is it a type `str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x = []
y = []
t = []

fig = plt.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')

readFile = open('C:\\Temp\\001.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if plotPair in '. ':
        # skip. or space
        continue
    if idx > 1:  # to skip the first line
        xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        t.append(time_string1)
        y.append(float(xAndY[1]))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='white')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)

plt.title('IRRADIANCE')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()

a = raw_input('enter to stop...')
```

Comment: when i run the module, i can see the graph but on the x-axis
i can only see the time but not the dates.

Comment: @toothberry  What kind of format do you want in your x-axis? 2014-07-22 or 2014-07 or?

Comment: for eg. 22/7/2014 23:57

Comment: @toothberry  Then you don't need strptime(), just t.append(time_string) after time_string = xAndY[0].

Comment: so the entire of this 'datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') is obsolete?

Comment: @toothberry  Yes. If it works, please confirm it as an answer.

Comment: when i run the module, i got a ValueError: invalid iteral for float(): 21/7/2014 0:00

Comment: hi could you solve the error? i tried changing the codes & search online and found something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261260/plot-date-and-time-x-axis-versus-a-value-y-axis-using-data-from-file
but can't seem to make it fit into my code

Comment: @toothberry  I've updated my answer. Don't forget to change filename to your own.

Comment: hi, it works (i have marked it as the answer) but when i maximise it, the program began to hang, i know is because my txt file is probably too large for the program to handle

Comment: and about the input was is the purpose behind it, thanks very much

Comment: * and about the input(a = raw input('enter to stop...')) what is the purpose behind it, thanks very much

Comment: @toothberry Welcome! No purpose, you can delete it.