# Can Pandas plot a histogram of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I've taken my Series and coerced it to a datetime column of dtype=`datetime64[ns]` (though only need day resolution...not sure how to change).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv')
column = df['date']
column = pd.to_datetime(column, coerce=True)
```

but plotting doesn't work:

```
ipdb> column.plot(kind='hist')
*** TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')
```

I'd like to plot a histogram that just **shows the count of dates by week, month, or year**.

Surely there is a way to do this in `pandas`?

Comment: can you show a sample of the df you have ?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Given this df:

```
        date
0 2001-08-10
1 2002-08-31
2 2003-08-29
3 2006-06-21
4 2002-03-27
5 2003-07-14
6 2004-06-15
7 2003-08-14
8 2003-07-29
```

and, if it's not already the case:

```
df["date"] = df["date"].astype("datetime64")
```

To show the count of dates by month:

```
df.groupby(df["date"].dt.month).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

`.dt` allows you to access the datetime properties.

Which will give you:

[image: groupby date month]

You can replace month by year, day, etc..

If you want to distinguish year and month for instance, just do:

```
df.groupby([df["date"].dt.year, df["date"].dt.month]).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

Which gives:

[image: groupby date month year]

Comment: If you have data spanning several years, all the 'january' data gets put into the same column and so on for each month.

Comment: Works, but for me (pandas 0.15.2) dates has to be written with capital D: df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month).count().plot(kind="bar")

Comment: @drevicko: That is expected I believe. @harbun: `date` or `Date` here are column names, so if your column with dates is called foo, it would be: `df.foo.dt.month`

Comment: @jeanrjc Looking again at the question, I guess you're right. For others like me who need to distinguish by years also, is there a simple way to `groupby` on combinations of two attributes of a columns data (e.g.: year and date)?

Comment: Is there a way to prepare the dates so that I can use seaborn.distplot() to plot the histogram of dates over dates?

Comment: @PanChao, ask another question with what you've tried

Comment: After groupping by year and month, one can set up index as datetime objects followingly: `df.index = [datetime.datetime(year=int(y), month=int(m), day=15) for y, m in df.index]`.

Comment: Did not work for me in my PyCharm python console. Any help?

Comment: I was getting a `Duplicate level name` error. Solved by adding `rename()` e.g. `df.groupby([df["date"].dt.year.rename('year'), df["date"].dt.month.rename('month')]).count().plot(kind="bar")`

Comment: cool answer! Remember to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the beginning, or you won't see any plot ...  instead, you would get  `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xe4241d0>` as output.

Also, you may need to type `plt.show()` if matplotlib is not configured to plot inline

Answer (score 18):

I think resample might be what you are looking for. In your case, do:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
# for '1M' for 1 month; '1W' for 1 week; check documentation on offset alias
df.resample('1M').count()
```

It is only doing the counting and not the plot, so you then have to make your own plots.

See this post for more details on the documentation of resample
[pandas resample documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001389/pandas-resample-documentation)

I have ran into similar problems as you did. Hope this helps.

Comment: `how` is deprecated. The new syntax is `df.resample('1M').count()`

Answer (score 13):

All of these answers seem overly complex, as least with 'modern' pandas it's two lines.

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.resample('M').size().plot.bar()
```

If you have a series with a `DatetimeIndex` then just run the second line

```
series.resample('M').size().plot.bar() # Just counts the rows/month
or
series.resample('M').sum().plot.bar(). # Sums up the values in the series
```

Comment: This appears to work only if you have a `DataFrame`, but not if all you have is a `Series`. Would you consider adding a note on that case?

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer, its simple and works perfectly. plus, unlike some of the other answers that ive tried, this plots correctly also periods of time with 0 counts. thanks Brian!

Answer (score 9):

### Rendered example

[image]

### Example Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Create random datetime object."""

# core modules
from datetime import datetime
import random

# 3rd party modules
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def visualize(df, column_name='start_date', color='#494949', title=''):
    """
    Visualize a dataframe with a date column.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : Pandas dataframe
    column_name : str
        Column to visualize
    color : str
    title : str
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    ax = (df[column_name].groupby(df[column_name].dt.hour)
                         .count()).plot(kind="bar", color=color)
    ax.set_facecolor('#eeeeee')
    ax.set_xlabel("hour of the day")
    ax.set_ylabel("count")
    ax.set_title(title)
    plt.show()


def create_random_datetime(from_date, to_date, rand_type='uniform'):
    """
    Create random date within timeframe.

    Parameters
    ----------
    from_date : datetime object
    to_date : datetime object
    rand_type : {'uniform'}

    Examples
    --------
    >>> random.seed(28041990)
    >>> create_random_datetime(datetime(1990, 4, 28), datetime(2000, 12, 31))
    datetime.datetime(1998, 12, 13, 23, 38, 0, 121628)
    >>> create_random_datetime(datetime(1990, 4, 28), datetime(2000, 12, 31))
    datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 19, 19, 24, 31, 193940)
    """
    delta = to_date - from_date
    if rand_type == 'uniform':
        rand = random.random()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('Unknown random mode \'{}\''
                                  .format(rand_type))
    return from_date + rand * delta


def create_df(n=1000):
    """Create a Pandas dataframe with datetime objects."""
    from_date = datetime(1990, 4, 28)
    to_date = datetime(2000, 12, 31)
    sales = [create_random_datetime(from_date, to_date) for _ in range(n)]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': sales})
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    df = create_df()
    visualize(df)
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution for when you just want to have a histogram like you expect it. This doesn't use groupby, but converts datetime values to integers and changes labels on the plot. Some improvement could be done to move the tick labels to even locations. Also with approach a kernel density estimation plot (and any other plot) is also possible.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(1582800000000000000, 1583500000000000000, 100, dtype=np.int64))})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df["datetime"].astype(np.int64).plot.hist(ax=ax)
labels = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
labels = pd.to_datetime(labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: Datetime histogram]

Comment: `labels = pd.to_datetime(labels).strftime('%-m/%-d')` can help clean up those tick labels.

Comment: How to plot several dataframes with different colors???

Comment: Use a for loop on the plot.hist line and use the argument „alpha“ to decrease the opacity so all histograms are visible. It might be necessary to define to color with the „color“ argument yourself. Please have a look at a matplotlib tutorial or documentation for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to work around this by (1) plotting with matplotlib instead of using the dataframe directly and (2) using the `values` attribute. See example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
ax.hist(column.values)
```

This doesn't work if I don't use `values`, but I don't know why it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I think for solving that problem, you can use this code, it converts date type to int types:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(int)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
```

for getting date only, you can add this code:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).normalize()
df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).normalize()
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of how to plot an ordered datetime histogram?

Comment: I think your problem at datetime type, you have to normalize before you plot

Comment: You also can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261260/plot-date-and-time-x-axis-versus-a-value-y-axis-using-data-from-file)

Answer (score 1):

I was just having trouble with this as well. I imagine that since you're working with dates you want to preserve chronological ordering (like I did.)

The workaround then is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
counts = df['date'].value_counts(sort=False)
plt.bar(counts.index,counts)
plt.show()
```

Please, if anyone knows of a better way please speak up.

EDIT:
for jean above, here's a sample of the data [I randomly sampled from the full dataset, hence the trivial histogram data.]

```
print dates
type(dates),type(dates[0])
dates.hist()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
0    2001-07-10
1    2002-05-31
2    2003-08-29
3    2006-06-21
4    2002-03-27
5    2003-07-14
6    2004-06-15
7    2002-01-17
Name: Date, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> <type 'datetime.date'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-f39e334eece0> in <module>()
      2 print dates
      3 print type(dates),type(dates[0])
----> 4 dates.hist()
      5 plt.show()

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in hist_series(self, by, ax, grid, xlabelsize, xrot, ylabelsize, yrot, figsize, bins, **kwds)
   2570         values = self.dropna().values
   2571 
-> 2572         ax.hist(values, bins=bins, **kwds)
   2573         ax.grid(grid)
   2574         axes = np.array([ax])

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   5620             for xi in x:
   5621                 if len(xi) > 0:
-> 5622                     xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
   5623                     xmax = max(xmax, xi.max())
   5624             bin_range = (xmin, xmax)

TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to float
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck a long time trying to plot time-series with "bar". It gets really weird when trying to plot two time series with different indexes, like daily and monthly data for instance. Then I re-read the doc, and matplotlib doc states indeed explicitely that bar is meant for categorical data.
The plotting function to use is step.

Answer (score 0):

With more recent matplotlib version, this limitation appears to be lifted.
You can now use Axes.bar to plot time-series.

With default options, bars are centered on the dates given as abscissis, with a width of 0.8 day. Bar position can be shifted with the "align" parameter and width can be assigned as a scalar or a list of the same dimension as abscissis list.

Just add the following line to have nice date labels whatever the zoom factor :

```
plt.rcParams['date.converter'] = 'concise'
```