# Plot a histogram using the int value when count() is giving me strings

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, histogram

In this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/can-pandas-plot-a-histogram-of-dates), the result is coming in a good way, but not good enough. The bins are strings, and the frequency plot is not real. It is like every item is a string, but I want them to be int. How can I do that?

What I want is to know how big is, having thousands of rows with a 'date' for each action, the normal volume of entries for a normal day. This is my code:

```
df["dayOfYear"] = df["date"].dt.dayofyear
plt.hist(df.groupby(df["dayOfYear"]).count())
```

It gives me the answer, but bins are strings, not int, so the X axis is a collection of strings, avoiding me of getting a nice gaussian distribution.

I tried to int() it, but it doesn't work for a pandas.

Any help? Thank you!
Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it. It was that simple as change:

```
plt.hist(df.groupby(df["dayOfYear"]).count())
```

for

```
plt.hist(df["dayOfYear"].groupby(df["dayOfYear"]).count())
```

Should I delete the question? Maybe it is a very stupid question. I am new to this, sorry.