# Creating a histogram and understanding both maplotlib axes and subplot

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I've just had some trouble piecing together matplotlib documentation particularly for my data set. I think I have a small enough block of code that shows all of my lack of understanding despite reading documentation. The documentation i've beeen trying to use for reference was initially this for creating a line graph https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

I've been trying to plot a numpy array, `post_records` containing two columns. I'm working with social media data, so the first column is for `post_ids` and the second is for `datetime_obj_col` that I managed to read from csv file using some scripting.

I managed to create a line graph with this data in matplotlib, but I don't quite know how to make a histogram.

Right now, nothing shows up when I run my program

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    hist, bins, patch_lst = ax.hist(post_records[:,1], bins=range(31)) # thought that bins could be a sequence, wanted to create 31 bins for 31 total days in a month
    ax.plot(hist, bins)
    ax.set_xlabel('Days')
    ax.set_ylabel('frequency')
    ax.set_title(r'Histogram of Time')

    plt.show() # shows nothing
```

- What do I need to pass to ax.plot? I'm unclear about how to pass in my x dataset

  - why isn't the window showing?

Edit with how to replicate this:

```
def create_dataframe_of_datetime_objects_and_visualize():
  datetime_lst = [1521071920000000000, 1521071901000000000, 1521071844000000000, 1521071741000000000, 1521071534000000000] # to get this variable  I loaded my original dataframe with 1980000, sliced the first 5 entries, then printed out the 'datetime_obj_col'. I can't exactly remember what this format is called, I think it's unix time.
  id_lst = [974013, 974072, 327212, 123890, 438201]

  for each in range(len(datetime_lst)):
    datetime_lst[each] = pd.to_datetime(datetime_lst[each], errors='coerce')
    datetime_lst[each] = datetime_lst[each].strftime("%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
    datetime_lst[each] = pd.to_datetime(datetime_lst[each], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True, format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
  datetime_lst = pd.Series(datetime_lst)

  df = pd.DataFrame({'tweet_id':id_lst, 'datetime_obj_col': datetime_lst})
  gb_var = df.groupby(df["datetime_obj_col"].dt.month)
  gb_var_count = gb_var.count()
  gb_var.plot(kind="bar")
  plt.show()
```

note that I am not using histogram anymore. But there should be two errors that come up, the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 918, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 936, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 2273, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 541, in f
    return self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 2941, in **call**
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 266, in generate
    self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 405, in _post_plot_logic_common
    self._apply_axis_properties(ax.yaxis, fontsize=self.fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 478, in _apply_axis_properties
    labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 1245, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 1396, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_major_locator()())
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1249, in **call**
    self.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1269, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1026, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib d
ate value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that h
as datetime units

Edit:

This is starting to seem like a bug related specifically to trying to use hist() to plot a column of datetime objects.

I took data from `post_records` which is a loaded numpy array that stores a 2d data set of 198000+ post ids and datetime objects.

This is the code for a function called create datetime objects. It opens a csv file "tweet_time_info_preprocessed.csv," which only has three columns: 'tweet_id" "`tweet_created_at_date`," and "`tweet_created_at_hour.`" The following is code to combine the `tweet_created_at_date` and `tweet_created_at_hour` columns into formatted datetime objects using the `pandas` library `to_datetime()` method.

Csv file sample

[image]

```
 def create_datetime_objects():  
   with open("post_time_info_preprocessed.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8') as time_csv:
         mycsv = csv.reader(time_csv)
         progress = 0
         for row in mycsv:
            progress +=1
            if progress == 1: #header row
               continue
            if progress % 10000 == 0:
               print(progress)
            each_post_datetime_lst = []
            each_post_datetime_lst.append(row[0])
            time_str = str(row[1]) + " " + str(row[2])
            a_date_object = pd.to_datetime(time_str, dayfirst=True, format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
            each_post_datetime_lst.append(a_date_object)
            post_and_datetime_lst.append(each_tweet_datetime_lst)
    numpy_arr_of_tweets_and_datetimes = np.array(tweets_and_datetime_objs)
    np.save(np_save_path, numpy_arr_of_tweets_and_datetimes)
```

then I have `visualize_objects_histogram()`

```
def visualize_objects_histogram():
    print("Visualizing timeplot as histogram")
    post_records= np.load("tweets_and_datetime_objects.npy")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=post_records, columns=['post_id', 'datetime_obj_col'])
     df_sliced = df[0:5]
     print(df_sliced)
     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     hist, bins, patch_lst = ax.hist(df_sliced['datetime_obj_col'], bins=range(5))
     ax.plot(hist, bins)
     ax.set_xlabel('Days')
     ax.set_ylabel('frequency')
     ax.set_title('Histogram of Time')

     plt.show()
```

So I sliced off 5 rows of the data frame and stored them into `df_slice`. I run this code, *a blank white window appears.* Printing `df_slice` gives

```
                  tweet_id     datetime_obj_col
   0  974072352958042112  2018-03-14 23:58:40
   1  974072272578166784  2018-03-14 23:58:21
   2  974072032177598464  2018-03-14 23:57:24
   3  974071601313533953  2018-03-14 23:55:41
   4  974070732777914368  2018-03-14 23:52:14
```

And there's also an error message that comes with the blank white window. It's very long.

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__i
nit__.py", line 1699, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
backends_backend_tk.py", line 227, in resize
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 12, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
backends\backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
figure.py", line 1475, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axes_base.py", line 2607, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 1190, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 1028, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = list(self.iter_ticks())  # iter_ticks calls the locator
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 971, in iter_ticks
    majorLocs = self.major.locator()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1249, in **call**
    self.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1269, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1026, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum -0.19500000000000003 is less than 1 and is an inv
alid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value
to an axis that has datetime units

This error message repeats 5 times with slightly different values for the "view limit." Possibly 5 error messages ffor my 5 records. I think the error messages are most closely related to the following online version of dates.py... Could be wrong : https://fossies.org/linux/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/dates.py (around line 1022, I'm going to check the actual file on my computer soon).

I'm going to try stuff from this post to see if it will help: [Can Pandas plot a histogram of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/can-pandas-plot-a-histogram-of-dates)

Edit 2:
The previous stackoverflow introduced me to two helpful methods, but they didn't work. I changed my visualize... function to the following

```
     def visualize_datetime_objects_with_pandas():
tweets_and_datetime_objects = np.load("tweets_and_datetime_objects.npy") # contains python datetime objects
print("with pandas")
print(tweets_and_datetime_objects.shape)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=tweets_and_datetime_objects, columns=['tweet_id', 'datetimeobj'])
pandas_freq_dict = df['datetimeobj'].value_counts().to_dict()
#print(pandas_freq_dict)
print(len(list(pandas_freq_dict.keys())))
print(list(pandas_freq_dict.keys())[0])
print(list(pandas_freq_dict.values())[1])

plt.plot(pandas_freq_dict.keys(), pandas_freq_dict.values())

#df = df.set_index('datetimeobj')
# changing the index of this dataframe to a time index
#df['datetimeobj'].plot(kind='line', style=['--'])

plt.show()
```

It gives the following output/error message.

```
     date-time temporal data visualization script
```

Visualizing timeplot as histogram

                  tweet_id  datetime_obj_col
datetime_obj_col
14                       5                 5
                  tweet_id  datetime_obj_col
datetime_obj_col
14                       5                 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 918, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 936, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 2273, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core
\groupby\groupby.py", line 541, in f
    return self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 2941, in **call**
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 266, in generate
    self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 405, in _post_plot_logic_common
    self._apply_axis_properties(ax.yaxis, fontsize=self.fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\plot
ting_core.py", line 478, in _apply_axis_properties
    labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 1245, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
axis.py", line 1396, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_major_locator()())
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1249, in **call**
    self.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1269, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "C:\Users\biney\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\
dates.py", line 1026, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib d
ate value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that h
as datetime units

Comment: The code itself looks correct, so one cannot know why it fails for you. Provide a [mcve], where you invent some data inside the code, such that people are able to run your code.

Comment: Honestly, the only other way I could provide a verifiable example is by uploading a numpy array online. But `post_records` is a variable with only the two columns I mentioned (a column for ids, and another column for datetimeobjects), it has 198000 records as expected (from printing out the shape),  and `post_records[:,1]` properly selects the column of only datetimeobjects as input to the histogram. 

trying to see how I could upload the numpy array, though if another way to reproduce this is to create an array that only has datetimeobjects to substitute for `post_records[:,1]`

Comment: No, as said you can simply create the data within your code.

Comment: I went into a lot of depth just because I'm starting to think this is some weird bug issue with datetime objects... take a look.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if you have any insight on why the error message at line 1026 (really, check line 1023) of dates.py on matplotlib, what does it mean... it seems to be coming up in the DateLocator class but that's all I can figure out.

Comment: I do have severe problems following the question, which does not show a [mcve] but two different (or more?) codes and several errors. I think the errors already explain what goes wrong, namely that datetime objects are plotted on non-datetime axes or vice versa. What I can say at this point is that you cannot create histogram plots of datetimes directly via `hist`.

Comment: what would it take at this point to make a minimal, complete, verifiable example? Should I write out code to create a small dateframe of the exact datetime objects in the screenshot I took of my csv file? Then people could copy and paste that and try running it on their matplotlib?

Comment: And secondly, " ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib d ate value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that h as datetime units..."

I could not tell what this error message, which I posted twice in sequence with all of the previous error messages, was saying. I couldn't tell that it was trying to portray that datetime objects were plotted on nondatetime axes.
If that's the problem, how to declare datetime axes objects, is that a parameter? I'm looking it up either way but...

Comment: 1) Yes, exactly. 2) No, the axis units will be determined by the first thing you plot to that axes. If the first thing is `ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])` it will be numeric, if it is `ax.plot([datetime(2018,2,4),datetime(2018,2,25)],[1,2])` it will be datetimes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest See the edit I most recently made, that has code to reproduce the error.