# Plot a histogram of dates

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram of dates from a pandas dataframe. I have had a look at this question [Can Pandas plot a histogram of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27365467/9988108) and some others, and while this works it is plotting a bar chart instead of a histogram.
Is there an easy way of plotting a histogram of dates or should I extract the year as numbers and plot a histogram of an array of numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly register a converter using:

```
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
```

By default you can't plot dates using the plotting functionality in pandas so you must explicitly register a converter like this.

As a very simple example try:

```
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('1/1/2019')]*8 + [pd.to_datetime('2/1/2019')]*4})
df['date'].hist()
```

which will return:

[image]