# Problems to plot a hist from a sales df.csv

Tags: numpy, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, histogram

Basically i looked for any resource in internet and i don't really know. This code is one of the thousands that i been tried.

```
plt.hist(df.Column, bins=bins)
```

> "Invalid syntax"

The df is group by months, and i want to plot an histogram that show the distribution of sales for each month. There are a column 'MONTHS' and a column 'TOTAL UNITS' (means the total units that has been sold). I would really appreciate any kind of help about hist. Thank u!

Comment: See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/can-pandas-plot-a-histogram-of-dates)

Comment: Made the code portion clearer.